# How to request POST using RestTemplate, authorized using user password

Tags: spring, rest

Can some one tell how I can use RestTemplate to POST a HttpEntity object using Authorization. I am using below code in test application

---

---

---

Client Side :

```
public class FifthWay extends Thread {

    public void run() {
        String plainCreds = "anuj:khare";
        byte[] plainCredsBytes = plainCreds.getBytes();
        byte[] base64CredsBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(plainCredsBytes);

        String base64Creds = new String(base64CredsBytes);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Creds);

        HttpEntity<String> postRequest = new HttpEntity<String>("FifthWay",headers);

        RestTemplate rt = new RestTemplate();
        rt.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
        rt.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());

        String postUri = new String("http://169.194.48.182:8080/trade-capture-service/deals/persist");

        ResponseEntity<String> responseForPost = rt.exchange(postUri,HttpMethod.POST, postRequest, String.class);
        String responseStringForPost = responseForPost.getBody();
        System.out.println(responseStringForPost);
    }

}
```

---

---

---

Server side :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/deals")
public class RestController {
...
...
@RequestMapping(value = "/check", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody
    String justACheck() {
        System.out.println("It Works");
        return "It works";
    }
```

---

---

---

Getting errors like :

```
Exception in thread "Thread-4" org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 415 Unsupported Media Type
```

OR

```
Exception in thread "Thread-4" org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request
```

Please help

Comment: Server Side :

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/deals")
public class RestController {
...

Comment: Try `exchange` of RestTemplate. You can do both POST and GET with it.

Comment: I am doing using exchange only, but is not helping

Comment: I am posting an example as an answer of RestTemplate with exchange. modify it to suit your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example of RestTemplate exchange :

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
 HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
 final HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(restCanvas, requestHeaders);
return restTemplate.exchange(canvasAddUrl + value, HttpMethod.POST, entity, Integer.class);
```

Here canvasAddURL is the URL you wish to call with context-path. If you want to add a cookie to it, lemme know, i have removed that code as it is most of the time not necessary. The return value for this is `ResponseEntity<Integer>` . Check it out.

Comment: May be the nediaType that I am using MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE. Do you know what MediType should we use for passing HttpEntity Object

Comment: What mediatype have you used in method, accessed by canvasAddUrl

Comment: No, I don't set media-type, not required for me.

Comment: Should NOT be perfectly REST then